# How to store API Tokens in MariaDB?

Tags: rest, mariadb

I have an API, and I want to find a secure mechanism to store them in MariaDB v10.5.

Here are a few options I have in mind:

1. Hash the API Key and compare the hashed user key with the database value. However, the user won't be able to check the API apart from the generation.
2. Encrypt the values usinsg a reversible encryption. The user is able to consult the key anytime.

Are there any most suitable options?

Comment: Which MariaDB version? There's a few new options in later versions. Avoid 2 - re-issuing tokens is pretty easy and they don't need to be the same if reissued.

Comment: MariaDB version 10.5

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt not to write a API security guide the key requirements of a API key are:

- Secrecy including non-guessability

For an API key to be non guessable it should contain at least 128 bits of random data (probably opinion based, but as AES128 key is secure this is too). For convenience to the user presenting it in a base64 (or other encoding mechanism) to add a little verification possibility to differentiate the different forms of white space (and other characters).

So on the database side, 128 bits of data is `BINARY(16)`. A MariaDB-10.11+ would use [RANDOM_BYTES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/random_bytes/) however any application language can provide random bytes in some form. As its BINARY ensure to use prepared statements to bind the value in the `insert`/`select` queries rather than trying to SQL escape it.

Hashing a value like a password doesn't actually increase the bits of randomness associated with its value. Stick with random bytes, and if possible cryptographicly secure bytes to avoid possible pseudo random generator prediction.

If its encrypted, it can be decrypted, which just exposes the API to be abused. Don't do this. Allow a user to generate multiple API keys and don't show the API key after the first time its generated. Like credit cards maybe allow the last few (8 bits, 2 hex digits) to be exposed in the interface and the device that uses the API key as a check.

Note: OWASP have some good security guides [API Security Top 10 2023](https://owasp.org/www-project-api-security/).